# How to inline JSON object into javascript with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, json, thymeleaf

I would like to use an autocomplete jquery component in my Thymeleaf template. The autocomplete function of Materializecss front-end framwork looks like this:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
    },
    limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
    },
    minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
  });
```

As you can see I need a data object including the list of elements. I would like to embed this variable from server side as this list is a dynamic one. As the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining) says

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" th:src="@{/js/example.js}"></script>
```

Based on the documentation the following example should work:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: [[${companies}]],
        limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
        onAutocomplete: function(val) {
          // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
        },
        minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
      });
```

The problem is that Thymeleaf does not inline anything in this case. Embedding serverside variables or command objects work fine with Thymeleaf but I can not make it work for javascript.
I use Spring Boot 1.5.4, Thymeleaf 3.0.2

Comment: What do you mean when you say Thymeleaf does not inline anything in this case?

Where is the js code going to be?
In the template statically?

Comment: @inoabrian my javascript file is external to the html.

Answer (score 1):

The `th:inline="javascript"` only works if your scripts are inline, that is in the HTML template between `<script>` and `</script>`.

If you have a separate javascript file and Thymeleaf expressions you want to evaluate in it, you need to process that js file through Thymeleaf separately using the JAVASCRIPT Template Mode.

Comment: It sounds reasonable. Can you tell me how can I do that? I use Spring Boot and it's auto-configuration. The default template mode is HTML. How can I specify different template mode for the .js files? I also do not understand why javascript template mode is not the default for js files

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: [($ {
        companies
    })], // use  '(', ')'
    limit: 20,
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {},
    minLength: 1
});
```

Try the above code. I also experienced that.

Comment: data: [ ( ${companies} ) ], /* unescape */,

data: [ [ ${companies} ] ], /* escape */

, Unescape and Escape  Expression are different each other